# pygame.image.load not doing anything

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to follow a tutorial to make a game with python and the pygame library. In the tutorial, this is used to set the icon of the window:

```
icon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```

It does changes the icon, but to another generic icon which is not 'icon.png' at all!
icon.png is in the same directory as my .py, and I get no error message.

What is happening?

Comment: That will load `'icon.png'` from whatever your working directory is when you run the app.  If you want it from the same path as the script, then you have to use something like `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to extract that directory name.

Comment: maybe first use `'/full/path/to/icon.png'` to make sure you load correct image. You can also check `os.getcwd()` to see `Current Working Directory`. You may run code in different folder and then it may load image from different folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you have come across was a problem with the tutorial video, not you that is the correct code I suggest watching/finding a new totorial.